# How to change the color of carousel NavigationArrows/NavigationIndicators in ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, sass, ng-bootstrap

I use ng-bootstrap carousel (version `^12.1.2`) but I wanted to change the color of `NavigationArrows` and `NavigationIndicators` because the user cannot see these on a white background.

I referred to several related questions on StackOverflow and came up with a solution as follows to change the color of the NavigationIndicators successfully.

```scss
:host ::ng-deep .carousel-indicators button
{
  background-color: #222831 !important;
  /*more custom style*/
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: grey !important;
}
```

But IntelliJ IDEA suggests that `::ng-deep` is deprecated.
Warning: `Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative`

Question:
What is the better way to change the color of `NavigationArrows` and `NavigationIndicators`?

Additional information:
Angular CLI: 13.3.7
Node: 16.15.0
Package Manager: npm 8.5.5
OS: win32 x64

[ng-bootstrap Carousel documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api)

Comment: if you put the .css (without host and ng-deep) in "styles.css" is applied to all the application -and is good all your carousels have the same appearance-

Answer (score 0):

sorry if I'm late

in your style.scss add these:

1- for arrows <<  >>

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon{
 background-image: url('https://apufpel.com.br/assets/img/seta_prim.png')
 // or any other styling you need
}

.carousel-control-next-icon{
 background-image: url('https://apufpel.com.br/assets/img/seta_ult.png')
 // or any other styling you need
}
```

2- for indicators --- (to change it to dots for example)

```
.carousel-indicators button
{
  width : 8px!important;
  height: 8px !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 5px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to swap the default color from white to a darker color.

```
.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next {
    filter: invert(100%); 
}
```